# Get Value from an array with foreach

Tags: php, arrays

i've an format array like this

```
Array ( 

[0] => stdClass Object ( [subscriptionContractId] => 20878 [merchantId] => 10062 [merchantName] => LinkIT360 [startDate] => 2015-07-02 03:27:39.000 [endDate] => 2015-07-04 03:27:39.000 [operatorCode] => 60201 [operatorName] => Mobinil-EGY [status] => 2 [isVerified] => 1 [initialPaymentproductId] => [initialPaymentDate] => [recurringPaymentproductId] => game_sku_1 [productCatalogName] => Game [autoRenewContract] => 1 [msisdn] => 201200000000 [customerAccountNumber] => 201200000000 [subscriptionContractName] => Game [nextPaymentDate] => 2015-07-03 03:27:39.000 [lastPaymentDate] => 2015-07-02 03:27:39.000 [subscriptionContractHistory] =>Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [subscriptionContractId] => 20878 [status] => 2 [isMerchantNotified] => 1 [paymentTransactionId] => [date] => 2015-07-01 03:27:53.290 ) ) [subscriptionContractLogs] => ) 

[1] => stdClass Object ( [subscriptionContractId] => 20861 [merchantId] => 10062 [merchantName] => LinkIT360 [startDate] => 2015-07-01 11:31:47.000 [endDate] => 2015-06-30 11:32:05.150 [operatorCode] => 60201 [operatorName] => Mobinil-EGY [status] => 5 [isVerified] => 1 [initialPaymentproductId] => [initialPaymentDate] => [recurringPaymentproductId] => game_sku_1 [productCatalogName] => Game [autoRenewContract] => 1 [msisdn] => 201200000000 [customerAccountNumber] => 201200000000 [subscriptionContractName] => Game [nextPaymentDate] => [lastPaymentDate] => 2015-07-01 11:31:47.000 [subscriptionContractHistory] => Array ( [0] => 
stdClass Object ( [subscriptionContractId] => 20861 [status] => 2 [isMerchantNotified] => 1 [paymentTransactionId] => [date] => 2015-06-30 11:31:55.530 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [subscriptionContractId] => 20861 [status] => 5 [isMerchantNotified] => 1 [paymentTransactionId] => [date] => 2015-06-30 11:32:05.977 ) ) [subscriptionContractLogs] => ) 

[2] => stdClass Object ( [subscriptionContractId] => 20860 [merchantId] => 10062 [merchantName] => LinkIT360 [startDate] => 2015-07-01 11:29:37.000 [endDate] => 2015-06-30 11:30:19.887 [operatorCode] => 60201 [operatorName] => Mobinil-EGY [status] => 5 [isVerified] => 1 [initialPaymentproductId] => [initialPaymentDate] => [recurringPaymentproductId] => game_sku_1 [productCatalogName] => Game [autoRenewContract] => 1 [msisdn] => 201200000000 [customerAccountNumber] => 201200000000 [subscriptionContractName] => Game [nextPaymentDate] => [lastPaymentDate] => 2015-07-01 11:29:37.000 [subscriptionContractHistory] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [subscriptionContractId] => 20860 [status] => 2 [isMerchantNotified] => 1 [paymentTransactionId] => [date] => 2015-06-30 11:30:10.267 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [subscriptionContractId] => 20860 [status] => 5 [isMerchantNotified] => 1 [paymentTransactionId] => [date] => 2015-06-30 11:30:20.687 ) ) [subscriptionContractLogs] => )

[3] => stdClass Object ( [subscriptionContractId] => 20859 [merchantId] => 10062 [merchantName] => LinkIT360 [startDate] => 2015-07-01 11:27:33.000 [endDate] => 2015-06-30 11:27:57.683 [operatorCode] => 60201 [operatorName] => Mobinil-EGY [status] => 5 [isVerified] => 1 [initialPaymentproductId] => [initialPaymentDate] => [recurringPaymentproductId] => game_sku_1 [productCatalogName] => Game [autoRenewContract] => 1 [msisdn] => 201200000000 [customerAccountNumber] => 201200000000 [subscriptionContractName] => Game [nextPaymentDate] => [lastPaymentDate] => 2015-07-01 11:27:33.000 [subscriptionContractHistory] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [subscriptionContractId] => 20859 [status] => 2 [isMerchantNotified] => 1 [paymentTransactionId] => [date] => 2015-06-30 11:27:42.173 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [subscriptionContractId] => 20859 [status] => 5 [isMerchantNotified] => 1 [paymentTransactionId] => [date] => 2015-06-30 11:27:58.467 ) ) [subscriptionContractLogs] => )
```

i want to take this value `[subscriptionContractId] => 20859`
PFB my code

```
foreach($getContract as $key =>$value) { 
   $cancel = $getContract[$key]->subscriptionContractId;      
   $this->data['res'] = $cancel;
}
```

with that above code only showing single value of record, meanwhile record is around 27 records.

and another code, i try to rectify with initialize array, PFB.

```
  $cancel = array()
  foreach($getContract as $key =>$value) { 
     $cancel[] = $getContract[$key]->subscriptionContractId;      
     $this->data['res'] = $cancel;
  }
```

i need only the value, of the array such as 20879, etc. eventhough i use double loop to extract particular array it only show the last record on 10663.

Please help

Comment: `$value->subscriptionContractId;`. While looping, $key is the index (either 0, 1, 2, 3 and so on) and $value is the Object, assuming `$getContract` is an `array` http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f60187c3ca44f580d6118e662a95912f087b4fc7

Comment: what is your expected output? array of values ?

Comment: Also, change: `$this->data['res'] = $cancel;` to `$this->data['res'][] = $cancel;` and define `$data['res']` as an `array`, else you're going to **overwrite its value everytime which will cause you to be able to retrieve only the last value you've retrieved.** .

Comment: thanks all, already got a clue :)

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your code as follows (see [php documenation about foreach](http://php.net/manual/de/control-structures.foreach.php) for more background):

```
$cancel = array();
foreach($getContract as $value) { 
    $cancel[] = $value->subscriptionContractId;      
    ...
}
```

This way, in every iteration `$value` is assigned one value from your `getContract` array, with it's key just being omitted. Then you can store the value's `subscriptionContractId` in your `$cancel` array to do whatever you are planning to do.

**Note:** [briosheje](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2275797/briosheje) is right about the line:

```
$this->data['res'] = $cancel;
```

`$this->data['res']` is overwritten in *every iteration*. As you are overwriting it with the your `$cancel` array, your code should still work, but your doing unnecessary work here, as your array might be subjected to further change in the next iteration.

My advice would be to move this line *after* your loop brackets ended, so that your result is saved just once:

```
...
foreach($getContract as $value) {
    ...
}
$this->data['res'] = $cancel;
```